# How can I remove a HDD from the "Devices" list in the file browser?

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, filemanager

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a new 11,3 Macbook Pro (dual booting) and I see this random HDD (looks like my cryptswap partition) listed under Devices in my file browser.

[image: File Browser]

As you can see it's a bit of an eyesore and I can't even access it:

[image]

How can I remove this from this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press Windows key and search for the application called "Disks"
2. Select the HDD that contains the partition that you want to hide
3. At the right, select the partition to hide and press the "More Actions" >> "Edit Mount Options..."
4. In the "Mount Options" window, select "OFF" for "Automatic Mount Options" and uncheck the "Show in user interface" box (also "Mount at startup" if you won't use it)

[image: Capture of "Mount Options" dialog]

Answer (score 0):

You can use GParted and a Live System and mark the partition as hidden. Nautilus doesn't offer such functionality hence you may have to use some Filesystem tools to make your wishes true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on it, and hitting "remove?" If that doesn't work, then it may be corrupted. Ubuntu has a funky way of dealing with corrupted HDD's (I have experience :)) If it's a partition, then there's no way to "physically" remove it from the system. You can just hit the "remove" button. If that doesn't work, then something is wrong with it.

Hope that helps!
--Michael